# Trying to increment different field values to a single variable in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is what I'm trying to do.

I have a form with different fields set up in the following structure:

```
     <input type="text" id="revenue-1" />
     <input type="text" id="revenue-2" />
     <input type="text" id="revenue-3" />
     <input type="text" id="revenue-4" />
     <input type="text" id="revenue-5" />
```

I get the values by using the following code:

```
      $("input[id^='revenue-']").keyup(function(e) {
            var revenue = $("#revenue-"+formNumber).val();
      });
```

Here is what I want to do, I want to get the values and increment each time.
For example, if revenue-1 is 90 and revenue-2 is 100 the total value of those fields automatically?

Basically, I want to get all the numeric values of all of the fields to add up each time I enter a value on the form and it will display elsewhere.

Thank you,
Kevin Davis

Comment: "*[If] revenue-1 is 90 and revenue-2 is 100 the total value of those fields automatically*" - the total value of fields automatically *what*? I'm assuming you're trying to find the total of all those `<input>` elements, but is that really what you want? If so, where should that total go?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Where is `formNumber` defined? Also, at what time do you want to perform the calculation?

Comment: The formNumber was defined, however, every time I defined it, the previous value gets overridden.

Comment: Please edit the question to show a more complete example of your code (including the definition of `formNumber` and where you set its value, and also a demo of the output you want to achieve. Right now the question makes very little sense, and the above questions need to be addressed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following.

```js
$(function() {
  function calcTotal() {
    var c = 0;
    $("[id^='revenue']").each(function() {
      var v = $(this).val();
      if (parseInt(v)) {
        c += parseInt(v);
      }
    });
    return c;
  }

  $("[id^='revenue']").keyup(function(event) {
    console.log(event.key, calcTotal());
  });
});
```

```css
input[type='text'] {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="revenue-1" />
<input type="text" id="revenue-2" />
<input type="text" id="revenue-3" />
<input type="text" id="revenue-4" />
<input type="text" id="revenue-5" />
```

This examines each of the fields, and if they have a number entry, will combine them with any other fields.

Remember that Text Fields result in String content. So if the user enters `1`, the `.val()` will respond with `"1"`, a String. So to perform a math calculation, we need to use `parseInt()` to cast it as a Integer.

See More: https://api.jquery.com/each/